# Correct way to offset headers while looping through a filtered list?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

In the below code i'm trying to use a for loop through a filtered list.
Without the offset the loop is going through each field and copying the data multiple times. With the offset its skipping rows.

How can I rephrase this to only loop through each row once, and skip the header row?

```
        'Offset Placement Wrong
        Set rngVisible = activeSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0)

        For Each rngCell In rngVisible

                    Rows(rngCell.Row).Select
                    Selection.Copy

                    Sheets(2).Select

                    'Skip Headers
                    Cells(2 + rowsRelocated, 1).Select
                    activeSheet.Paste

                    Sheets(1).Select

                    'row increment
                    rowsRelocated = rowsRelocated + 1

         Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrict the range to one column of your filter.

```vb
    Dim rngVisible As Range, RowsRelocated As Long, rngCell As Range
    Set rngVisible = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    RowsRelocated = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngVisible.Cells
         If rngCell.Row > 1 Then
            rngCell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(2 + RowsRelocated, 1)
            RowsRelocated = RowsRelocated + 1
         End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all filtered visible data at once from Sheets(1) to Sheets(2)...

```
Sub test()

Dim allData As Range, FilteredData As Range, rngVisible As Range, TargetRange As Range

Set allData = Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'Instead of currentregion you could mention actual range if it contains blank rows.
Set FilteredData = allData.Offset(1, 0).Resize(allData.Rows.Count - 1, allData.Columns.Count)
Set rngVisible = FilteredData.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set TargetRange = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 0)
'Assuming that Row 1 in Sheets(2) is header, Copy visible data from A2
rngVisible.Copy TargetRange

End Sub
```