# Excel VBA reconciliation

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

I have excel workbook and i need to compare column B and column W if column B & W data is the same need to copy an entire row to a newsheet(sheetname "Reconciled") column B data is date format like this (2020-02-01 07:55:08.0) column W date format is like this (27/01/2020) Column B & W need to compare with the date.
this code date is selected but it is working but it is wrong.

```
Sub runThrough(cbpath As String, bspath As String)

Dim  newcashBook, newbankstmt As Worksheet
Dim cashbook, Bankstmt As Workbook
Dim i, j As Long
Dim cbRecords, bsRecords rng As String

Set cashbook = Workbooks.Open(cbpath)

   'copy data from another workbook
 Set newcashBook = cashbook.Sheets(1) 
 newcashBook.Range("A1:Z1048576").Copy
 cashbook.Close

      'paste data to W1 row from another workbook
    Set newbankstmt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet0") 
    newbankstmt.Range("W1").PasteSpecial


 For i = 2 To 100
  Set newbankstmt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet0")
  ' Sheet0 is activeworkbook active worksheet
   Rows.Cells(i, 2).Select

  Rows.Cells(i, 2).Select
      For j = 2 To 100 

        Rows.Cells(j, 31).Select

                 If (i = j) Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"   'check data same or not
                 Else
                    Debug.Print "wrong"

                 End If
 Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim cashbook, Bankstmt As Workbook` declares `cashbook` as variant, `Bankstmt` as workbook. You seem to intend `Dim cashbook as Workbook, Bankstmt As Workbook'.

Comment: It can be done with excel formula and filter... And you can have the same procedure for VBA... for filter see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634967/9808063

Comment: Do you need to paste the format, also? Otherwise, you can avoid selecting, using clipboard and the code will run much more faster. You are talking about some cells (Date) format. Where do you want using this aspect in your code? When you use `If (i = j) Then` what do you expect to compare? Something like  `2 = 2`?

Comment: @FaneDuru, no no  i don't need paste the format but  if column B and W date are same then need to copy column A to column W (entire row) to activeworkbook newworksheet

Comment: Please try explaining in words what your code tries to do. Do you mean `If CDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) = CDate(Cells(i, j).Value)` maybe...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I didn't understand the previous question

Comment: @FaneDuru, I need to use 2 For loop, I included my code my question

Comment: My problem is that I cannot understand your code... Even if, usually I better  understand the code then English... I asked you "When you use `If (i = j) Then` what do you expect to compare?". Can you try answering this question? Your task seems to be a simple one, but I never start working a piece of code if I am not sure I understood what is to be done...

Comment: @FaneDuru, i used i variable for 1st For loop and j variable used for 2nd For loop, variable i affect with column B data and j variable effect with column W data. sometimes I will be wrong (i=j) .i used this condition for identity same record column B and W data.

Comment: And do you want to compare `2` with `3`, like your code does, or Cells values defined according to the two Long variables? Meaning cells having the `i` row and column `2` with cell having row `i` and column `j`... Would this understanding be correct?

Comment: i want to compare column B and column W data,  it is mean i need to get B column cell values one by one and get column W cell value one by one and check the column B and column W equal or not if it is equal then match entire row copy to new worksheet        (cells have the i row and column 2, j row and cloumn 23)

Comment: 2020-02-01 07:55:08.0 looks like either a custom date format or text, which is it ?

Answer (score 1):

The below check if both date are valid and check if there are the same. Modify and use:

```
Sub populate_sales()

    Dim bDate As Date, wDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Check if both date are valid
        If IsDate(.Range("B1").Value) And IsDate(.Range("W1").Value) Then

            bDate = Year(.Range("B1").Value) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(.Range("B1").Value), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(.Range("B1").Value), 2)
            wDate = Year(.Range("W1").Value) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(.Range("W1").Value), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(.Range("W1").Value), 2)

            If bDate = wDate Then
                'Copy
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid dates"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a code based on what I could deduce from your question and comments. So, the code copy, as fast as possible (using array) the content of `cashbook.Sheets(1)` in `newbankstmt.Range("W1")`.

Then it iterates between 100 rows and, if "B" cell Date on a specific row is equal with the "W" cell Date of the same row, then the rage "A:W" address of the respective row is returned in Immediate Window and the code is stopped. You can go to the next such occurrence pressing F5. In order to see the returned value in Immediate Window, you must press Ctrl + G.

If this is what you needed, please confirm and I will show you how that ranges can be also loaded in another array and paste at once in a new sheet, or wherever you need, if clearly explain where...

This code doesn't care about the cell (date) format. But, the code would work **only if both cells in discussion (B and W) are of Date type**.

```
Sub runThrough(cbpath As String, bspath As String)
 Dim newcashBook As Worksheet, newbankstmt As Worksheet
 Dim cashbook As Workbook, Bankstmt As Workbook
 Dim i As Long, dateB As Date, dateW As Date, arrC As Variant

 Set cashbook = Workbooks.Open(cbpath)
   'copy data from cashbook:
   Set newcashBook = cashbook.Sheets(1)
   'input the big range in arrC array:
   arrC = newcashBook.Range("A1:Z1048576").value
 cashbook.Close

    'copy the arrC content starting from W1:
    Set newbankstmt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet0")
    newbankstmt.Range("W1").Resize(UBound(arrC, 1), UBound(arrC, 2)).value = arrC


 For i = 2 To 100 'why To 100?
    dateB = newbankstm.Cells(i, "B").value
    dateW = newbankstm.Cells(i, "W").value
    If DateSerial(Year(dateB), Month(dateB), Day(dateB)) = DateSerial(Year(dateW), Month(dateW), Day(dateW)) Then
        Debug.Print "Range to be copied: " & newbankstm.Range(newbankstm.Cells(i, 1), _
                                                    newbankstm.Cells(i, "W")).Address
        Stop
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```